# Create apk from libgdx project

Tags: libgdx

What is the basic procedure to create the signed apk for my libGDX project? I am new to libGDX so provide some guidance.

I am talking about deploying apk to the Android market. I have to ask this question because my Galaxy SX2 display only blank screen.

Comment: -1 Question shows no research effort.

Comment: I have to ask this question because my Galaxy SX2 display only blank screen

Comment: That's important information for your question. Your question should include what you've tried, and why you think it didn't work.

Comment: I want to launch the game in android market so I required signed apk so I require basic steps to create signed apk in libGDX

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the APK for debugging on Android, I wouldn't worry. Once you have your project setup, plugging your phone in will make Eclipse automatically upload and run the APK on your phone.

The Android project in your workspace will generate the APK in \bin. In my case, I had a `game-core` project and an `android-specific` project, and my APK shows up in `\android-specific\bin`.

**Edit:** since you mentioned deploying your app to the store, you need to sign it. Detailed instructions here [here on their wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-android):

> - Right click your Android project and select "Export"
> - Select "Android -> Export Android Application"
> - Make sure the project you want to export is your project, select next
> - Select or create your keystore. If you are new to Android development, a keystore is used to sign your applications and is required for putting your application on the market. More information is available at: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
> - Select your alias to sign with and enter the password. If you don't have an alias or want to create a new alias, select create new key and select next.
> - Now select the destination of where you want your app being exported to. This will export an .apk file in the selected directory capable of being uploaded to Google Play (formerly Android Market) and alternative app stores.
> - Select finish and your .apk will be built!

Comment: I want to launch the game in android market so I required signed apk so I require basic steps to create signed apk in libGDX

Comment: Are you talking about deploying your app to the Andriod market, or running debug versions?

Comment: I am talking about deploying apk to the Android market

Comment: Updated @Siddharth